# Type safe enum for dependency injection

Tags: java, enums, guice

I wanted an easy way for non coders to map new "Tests" with "Test" Types with the least amount of code change, using Guice for dependency injection.  I like the simplicity, but not the obvious lack of type safety.  Any suggestions to make this better?

```
public enum TestType {

    TEST_TYPE_1("TEST-1", Test1.class), 
    TEST_TYPE_2("TEST-2", Test2.class), 
    TEST_TYPE_3("TEST-3", Test3.class), 
    TEST_TYPE_4("TEST-4", Test4.class), 
    TEST_TYPE_5("TEST-5", Test5.class);

    private final String testType;
    private final Class<TestIF> tester;

    private <TestIF> TestType(String testType, Class<TestIF> tester)    {       
        this.testType = testType;
        this.tester = (Class<tester.TestIF>) tester;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.testType;
    }

    public Class<TestIF> tester() {
        return this.tester;
    }
}
```

The "Test" would get instantiated like this:

```
TestIF tester = Guice.createInjector().getInstance(testType.tester());    
tester.execute();
```

Comment: Your use of generics is a bit confusing here, given that you use `TestIF` both as a generic type *parameter* and as a concrete class (interface) name.  Can you clean up that ambiguity?

Comment: What happens if you replace your generic type TestIF by T extends TestIF?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Yes, I believe that should help, although I'll need to use ? extends TestIF in the constructor.  It forces my Tests to implement the TestIF, which should be enough in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helps force the Tests to implement TestIF, which is a bit safer in this case.

```
public enum TestType {

TEST_TYPE_1("TEST-1", Test1.class), 
TEST_TYPE_2("TEST-2", Test2.class), 
TEST_TYPE_3("TEST-3", Test3.class), 
TEST_TYPE_4("TEST-4", Test4.class), 
TEST_TYPE_5("TEST-5", Test5.class);

private final String testType;
private final Class<? extends TestIF> tester;

private <T extends TestIF> TestType(String testType, Class<? extends TestIF> tester)    {       
    this.testType = testType;
    this.tester = (Class<tester.TestIF>) tester;
}

public String toString() {
    return this.testType;
}

public Class<? extends TestIF> tester() {
    return this.tester;
}
```